# how to interpret KS test or Shapiro wilk test for ordinal criterion variable?

Tags: ordinal-data, normality-assumption, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

[image]

Here Rank is my dependent variable from level (Strongly disagree to strongly agree) and Pre_Sales_support is one of the independent variable. Due to smaller sample size of 15, I am taking shapiro-wilk test into account to check normality but my null hypothesis getting rejected for one level(p value for Strongly agreed .007) and accepted for another(p value for agreed .101) within same variable. How to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ordinal variables are obviously not normal. There's no point in testing what you know for certain *a priori* -- your data are not normal.
2. the intervals between adjacent categories in an ordinal variable are arbitrary (the variable is ordinal - if they were fixed quantities you could rescale to interval). It's not really meaningful to test for normality, since it depends on imposing an arbitrary scale choice.
3. The tests you propose are not suitable for variables that are not continuous

   a) the distribution of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic relies on continuity and will be highly conservative (and have correspondingly low power when used on a

   b) the distribution of the order statistics in the Shapiro-Wilk will be altered by the discreteness and hence, the statistic for it, to, won't have the right distribution.